In geometry nodes cannot connect attribute to cylinder
I am trying to use geometry nodes to do a type of world bar graph. Im using cylinders for the bars.  My data has longitude, latitude and a proportion field.  The proportion field is a number from 0-1

I am trying set the depth of the cylinder based on the proportion.  but am not able to link the Named attribute proportion to the cylinder's depth.  How do I get the height of the cylinder to be based on data?


just use the scale input of your "instance on points" node as input of a "combine xyz", where x=1, y=1, and z is your output from your "multiply node".
Note: you cannot plugin in a field value (which is the named attribute, diamond shaped input) into the depth input of the cylinder (which is a single value, round shaped input) because multiple values cannot be converted to one value. That's why you have to change that values later in your GN tree.
